# Predicting churn - deal with missing dates in time series and improve modelling result

Tags: python, time-series, predictive-modeling, churn

This is the follow up question for [General approach on time series for customer retention/churn in retail](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/61428/general-approach-on-time-series-for-customer-retention-churn-in-retail).

I have a time series of data in the following form:

```
| purchase_date    |    cutomer_id  |   num_purchases | churned |
   2018-10-31            id1              39             0
   2018-11-31            id1              0              0
   2019-01-31            id1              6              0
                         ...
   2019-03-31            id1              88            1
   2019-03-31            id2              300            0 
   2018-04-31            id2               2             1
   2019-02-31            id3               1             1
   2019-07-31            id4               100           0
     ...                 id5
```

I grouped the data by month and summed num_purchases by month. The churned column for user `id1` for example represents in which month customer churned. So `id1` in my case churned in March. Before this, to label who has churned or not, we sampled customers based on 2 months of inactivity  period from the churn date. I need to predict if a user is going to churn in a 2 months from now.

I am getting very bad prediction results using logistic regression for example and the churned column as a class column. I suspect this is because some users  like `id3` and `id4` appear only once (or very few number of times) and other users like `id1` appear a lot. I am not sure how to approach imputation in this case because these users just didn't exit before or after and I am not sure if it would make sense to impute them. Does anyone have idea on how to improve my model result?  I am getting 0.85 for accuracy, and 0 for precision, recall and F1.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interested to deal with it as a sequence classification problem. For instance, you could use HMM (Hidden Markov Model) or equivalent to classify the sequences. The data format would be:

```
ID:  sequence      label
id1: 39,0,6,...,88  1
id2: 300, 2         1
id3: 1              1
id4: 100            0
```

Some suggestions:

- Create more samples to balance also your dataset (e.g `id1   39, 0    0`)
- Possibly bin the variables (e.g. to the decimal `6 -> 10`, `39 -> 40`)

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it ok if I just pad sequences with zeros so they are all of the same length? I don't understand what do you mean with binning variables in this way?

Comment: The thing is you don't have to pad them with zeros. Each sequence can be an arbitrary length. I remember I used an HMM algorithm from Weka to do that. There should be more out there.

Comment: Depending on the approach that you choose you may need to bin them, in order to have a better model (i.e. simplify it). Then again I am not sure if that's necessary. Bining, in other words, can be like rounding the numbers up.

Comment: do you know similar package like weka in `python`.?

Comment: @IamTheRealFord the most similar library in Python that I used recently was the CRF Suite https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: yeah but i am looking to use hmm in sequence classification. Is it possible to do it.?